# cross-platform zip file creation

Tags: r, functional-programming

I'd like to create a zip archive from within R, and need maximal cross-platform compatibility, so I would prefer not to use a `system("zip")` command.

Within utils there's `zip.file.extract` (aka unzip), which uses [a lot of] c code, derived from zlib 1.1.3 within a file called dounzip.c I couldn't find any similar capabilities for creating zip files.

It's also tricky to construct a specific google query for "cran create zip" or equivalent!

Also, a tar will not suffice, I need to creating zip's to use as input for another set of non-R tools.

I'd appreciate any pointers?

cheers,
mark

Answer (score 1):

As usual the amazing [Omega Project for Statistical Computing](http://www.omegahat.org/) is a valuable resource! Take a look at the [Rcompression](http://www.omegahat.org/Rcompression/) package and try, for example, something like:

```
?gzip    
txt <- paste(rep("This is a string", 40), collapse = "\n")
v <- gzip(txt))
writeBin(v, "test.txt.zip")
```

HTH

Comment: hi Paulo,
thanks, that's getting closer to what i need.

What I didn't say clearly enough is that I have a directory full of various files which already exist... I then need to turn them, possibly recursively into a zip archive... from what I can tell: "This [Rcompression] package is a basic interface to the zlib and bzip2 facilities for compressing and uncompressing data that are in memory rather than in files"

Answer (score 1):

I think the command `gzfile()` may also do what you're looking for.  Also note that in the upcoming version 2.10.0 there are some enhancements to compression functions that may be relevant. (see https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/NEWS -- the svn server may ask you to accept a certificate)

Comment: thanks Peter,
there's a new tar() and untar() command coming in 2.10, but no zip() !!
mark